# Create an Http injectable in an Angular2 service?

Tags: dependency-injection, angular

I'm trying to wrap http in a service, so that all db access is passing through my channel

the issue is, services cannot have injectables passed to their constructor (right?) so I have to construct it all myself. I'm using the code:

```
import {Http,HTTP_BINDINGS,XHRBackend,BaseRequestOptions} from 'http/http';
import {Injector,bind} from 'angular2/di'

...

var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
              BaseRequestOptions,
              XHRBackend,
              bind(Http).toFactory(
                  function(backend, defaultOptions) {
                    return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
                  },
                  [XHRBackend, BaseRequestOptions])
            ]);

this.http = injector.get(Http);
```

but when trying to use it by:

```
this.http.get('./entities.json')
  //Get the RxJS Subject
  .toRx()
  // Call map on the response observable to get the parsed people object
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(e => this.entities = e);
```

I get an error:

> Error during instantiation of DBDriver! (Entities -> DBDriver).
>   angular2.dev.js:22367 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for function () {}! (function (_backend, _defaultOptions) { -> function (_browserXHR, _baseResponseOptions) { -> function () {})

Comment: Read this [blog article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html)

Comment: Thanks @EricMartinez this looks good. also solved by
    var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([HTTP_BINDINGS]);
    this.http = injector.get(Http);

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that HTTP is injected in your service 
Note **@Inject(http)** at de service constructor

```
@Inject(Http) public http: Http
```

Note that http, at least at angular2 alpha45, is outside angular lib, therefore you have to manually add http lib

```
<script src="/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.min.js"></script>
```

SERVICE

```
import {Http, Headers, HTTP_BINDINGS} from 'angular2/http';
import {Inject} from 'angular2/angular2'

constructor(@Inject(Http) public http: Http) {}

getQuote(): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get('http://localhost:3001/api/random-quote')
            .map(res => res.text())
            .subscribe(
                data => resolve(data),
                err => this.logError(err),
                () => console.log("Random Quote Complete")
            );
        }) 
    }
```

COMPONENT

```
import {Component, bootstrap, CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Http, Headers, HTTP_BINDINGS} from 'angular2/http';
import {ChuckService} from "./chuck-service";

@Component({
    selector: 'hello-app',
template: `
    {{quoteOfTheDay}}<br />
    <button (click) = "getQuote()">Get new quote</button><br /><br />
    `,
    directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ChuckService, HTTP_BINDINGS]
})

export class HelloApp {
    quoteOfTheDay: string = '';

    constructor(public _chuckService: ChuckService) {
    }

    getQuote(){
        this._chuckService.getQuote().then((resp) => this.quoteOfTheDay = resp);
    }
}

bootstrap(HelloApp);
```

INDEX.HTML

```
<script src="/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-csp-production.js"></script>
```